# How many calories does the Human Torch burn?

Tags: marvel, science, fantastic-four

I mean the guy has to burn a lot of calories, literally. So how many calories does he need to take in, to engulf himself in flames for at least an hour?

Assumption(?) for this question: he does draw at least a part of the needed energy from his body. In universe explanations preferred.

Comment: This assumes that turning on his torch powers actually draws calories from his body. I can think of only a few superheroes where that connection is made (that employing the powerz burns food calories).  Do you have any reason to believe it does in his case?

Comment: Fair point. Let's, for this question at least, assume he does.

Comment: There's [this](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0tYvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=johnny+storm+calories&source=bl&ots=-4DEDWZR5p&sig=Bd7DLp86tx0E_mCEwBVLoHMAV90&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU8tPS14zbAhUCVhQKHTbkDyMQ6AEITTAC#v=onepage&q=johnny%20storm%20calories&f=false), though it doesn't seem to be based on much canon, other than Johnny's weight. The science _seem_ plausible. TLDR: ~30 000 kcal to heat up and ~2 000 000 kcal to stay burning for 10 minutes. That's ~4000 peanut butter sandwiches. You lot do the multiplication by 6, I'm lazy. :p

Comment: @Paul I don't know if this question is off-topic. It seems to be asking for a scientific explanation like the above. Given the OPs belief is "lets say he does" that seems to suggest even further they want a scientific answer and not necessarily anything canonical and is therefore even more off-topic.

Comment: To the close voters: ["In-Universe Explanations — Even Based On Real Science — Are On-Topic"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7367/19561).

Comment: @SQB this isn't in universe, this seems quite clearly to be out of universe given the OP has no care for the facts in universe, as outlined in their comment above.

Comment: @Edlothiad then the answer should be "he doesn't, because X and Y".

Comment: @SQB except we're being told to assume he does. He doesn't would be a wrong answer.

Comment: the Torch _does_ use energy from his body... a special ATP-like chemical called AR-HP... and he burns at about 800F... so we could probably just do the math.

Comment: I can't see how an answer of the sort "There is no mention that his abilities require any calorie intake." cannot answer this question perfectly. It should be reopened.

Comment: @KutuluMike ATP is not used to store energy. Processes that need energy use ATP, but in turn ATP is produced by oxidizing fats, sugars, proteins and others. ATP is like the electricity travelling through the electric grid, it is what you use but you need the fuel/solar/nuclear energy as source.

Comment: Was this covered in *The Science of Super Heroes*? I remember the Flash was covered a lot.

Comment: Calories is a system of measurements, you can measure the calories burnt when burning a piece of wood. If we remove the part of the question that suggests he needs calories intake to burn, it should be answerable.

Comment: @CBredlow it is indeed, I linked it above (but [here it is again](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0tYvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=johnny+storm+calories&source=bl&ots=-4DEDWZR5p&sig=Bd7DLp86tx0E_mCEwBVLoHMAV90&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU8tPS14zbAhUCVhQKHTbkDyMQ6AEITTAC#v=onepage&q=johnny%20storm%20calories&f=false)). Unless you were refering to another _Science of Super Heroes_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to his write-up in the [Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Vol 1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1), Johnnie Storm's energetic fire mainly comes from the food that he consumes, which, in addition to giving him the appropriate amount of energy needed to run his human systems, also provides an indeterminate amount of energy (based on the extraction of *[additional "latent chemical-bonding energy"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TechnoBabble)*) that he can then use to power his psionic flight and fire. As such, **he doesn't need to eat more than a typical human who engages in the sort of moderate activity you'd associate with general exercise.**

> The Human Torch possesses the mental ability to control ambient heat energy and the physical ability to control ambient heat energy and the physical ability to transform his entire body, or portions of his body, into a firey, plasma-like state at will. **The cells of a normal human body convert energy from foodstuffs into a form of energy usable by the body, adenosine triphosphate (ATP). Among other mutagenic changes, the cosmic ray bombardment triggered a specific genetic-code rearrangement that caused the Human Torch's ATP production sites to generate a new form of energy-containing module. (Reed Richards has dubbed this molecule adenine riboheptaphosphene, AR-HP). This complex molecule not only provides ordinary bodily energy, but contains large stores of latent chemical-bonding energies**. Another favourable mutagenic change are his cells ability to utilise this extra energy by converting it into moderate-density, plasma-like state that is regulated by a sub-conscious mental field and can be modified by an act of will. When sufficient quantities of energy are consumed, the Torch unavoidably reverts to his solid state.
>
> ...
>
> **At an average rate of expenditure of energy, the Torch can maintain his plasma state for about 16.8 hours** before he is forced to revert to his solid state. The Human Torch's physical condition (health, injury or exhaustion) also limits his flame's duration.

Additionally he can absorb ambient heat from his surroundings without the need to burn his body's own reserves of energy.

> **The Human Torch has the ability to mentally control the ambient heat energy within his immediate environment** even when not in his plasma state. He can reduce objects temperatures to about thirty degrees Fahrenheit, raise them to several hundred degrees, or extinguish open flames. His radius of influence is about 80 feet. **The heat-energy he takes from the environment is absorbed into his own body and if he takes in a critical amount he will uncontrollably phase-change into his plasma state.**

Answer (score 0):

An unrealistic amount. [From the Marvel Wiki](https://marvelcomicsfanon.fandom.com/wiki/Jonathan_Storm_(Earth-1010)):

> The Human Torch possesses the mental ability to control ambient heat energy and the physical ability to transform his entire body, or portions of his body into a fiery, plasma-like state of will. The cells of a normal human body convert energy from foodstuffs into a form of energy usable by the body, adenosine triphosphate (ATP). Among other mutagenic changes, the cosmic ray bombardment triggered a specific genetic code rearrangement that caused the Human Torch's ATP production sites to generate a new form of energy containing molecule.

According to he can run at modest amounts for 16.8 hours, assuming standard consumption of a 2000 calories a day meal plan as recommended about 119 calories per hour.
As for calorie consumption, his powers convert the ambient heat energy released in human metabolism  as catalyst for his fire powers. Assuming

Comment: You need to do a better job of attributing your sources by actually linking to the source -- stating that you got it from "Marvel Wikia" or whatever doesn't cut it. Also, it looks like you were starting to write another sentence with "Assuming..." but didn't finish it.